# Callback function php?

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm having trouble with my project. I am trying to post something to the database via jQuery, but there is something wrong in my code and I am unable to figure out what.

Basically, I have a form:

```
<form id="addCartForm" method="POST" action="callback/additemtocart.php">
</form>
```

Inside the file `additemtocart.php` I have the following code:

```
$item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
$brand_id = $_POST['brand_id'];
$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

if(item_exists($item_id, $brand_id, $category_id, $_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    $errors[] = 'this item is already in your cart';
}
else
{
    //register the user
    $item_data = array(
        'user_id'         => $_SESSION['user_id'],
        'item_id'         => $item_id,
        'brand_id'        => $brand_id,
        'category_id'     => $category_id
    );

    add_item_to_cart($item_data);
    $cart[] = 'An item has been added to your cart!';
}
```

Once the user clicks on the item, I will execute the following code:

```
 $(".cart_item").click(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr("id");
        var array = name.split("|");

        var data = [];

        data.push({"item_id": array[0]});
        data.push({"brand_id": array[1]});
        data.push({"category_id": array[2]});

        $.post($("#addCartForm").attr("action"), data, function(info){

        });
    });

    $("#addCartForm").submit(function(){
        return false;
    });
```

Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Is your jQuery function inside a PHP file? The `post` function doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What is your desired output? What is the error you get? What is not working properly?

Comment: Alright, and how to make it sense?

Comment: ReferenceError: array is not defined
 
data.push({"item_id": array[0]});

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work the way you want it to.

Javascript/jQuery is executed client side, the PHP is executed server side. When the callback in jQuery is fired, there's no PHP server on the client to deal with this PHP you've got there.

What you want to do instead, is pass the array key and string as a parameter in the $.post, to the script on the server, which can then add the string to your errors array.

Like this:

```
    data.push({"item_id", array[0]});
    data.push({"brand_id", array[1]});
    data.push({"category_id", array[2]});

    data.push({"errors", "my error string"});

    $.post($("#addCartForm").attr("action"), data, function(info){
        //success message?
    });
```

Then in the action script, you'll be able to check for the get parameter $_POST['errors'], and add it to your PHP errors array.

```
if(isset($_POST['errors']) && !empty($_POST['errors'])){
   $errors = $_POST['errors'];
}
```

EDIT: That aside, given your edit, your error is that your array isn't defined, is it? You have arrays named array1 and array2 but you're then trying to access array[0], array[1] and array[2]. It should be array2[0], etc.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: I am doing the same thing here

Comment: you can echo something inside additemtocart.php and get the it within the info parameter

Comment: Yeah, but what you did in your code originally before your edit, was using php inside js, which won't be executed.

Comment: what about this error

SyntaxError: missing : after property id
data.push({"item_id", array[0]});

Comment: What syntax error? It was an undefined error a minute ago?! You keep changing the question!

Comment: It's data.push({"item_id": array[0]});   Use a colon, not a comma. It's JSON notation.

Comment: I am alerting the data but it seems that it's not defined 
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: They are defined! They're objects! JavaScript is an object oriented language. You can't alert an object, as it's not a string, just like you can't alert an array, you can alert an array's value, which would be a string, or an object's property, which will be your string. :) Access the object's parameters like data.item_id

Comment: I am alerting alert(data.item_id);
but I get undefined, I don't have experience with JSON

Comment: ok, console.log your data array, you'll see in your javascript console, drop down objects, you can the see the object name, it might be like data[0].item_id or data.item_id.value, you'll have to inspect your object with console.log();

Comment: ReferenceError: data is not defined
console.log(data);

Comment: Which variable are you trying to alert? data or info?

Comment: data, because I told you it is not defined